# Как создать условие, чтобы скрыть кнопку "читать далее" когда длина отрывка короче заданной длины?

Tags: wordpress

Как создать условие, чтобы скрыть кнопку "читать далее" когда длина отрывка короче заданной длины самого отрывка?
На вордпресс кнопка отображается у всех записей, даже когда длина текста отрывка короче 55 слов.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.